# dojo templatedmixin inside widget event behaviour

Tags: dojo

Observation:

Inside my template of a custom widget that I'm making, there's a line:

```
<input type="text"  data-dojo-props="placeHolder:'Search...'" data-dojo-attach-event="onchange: search"/>
```

This works fine as in on change, the search function of my widget is called. but the display is plain input box, not dijit's fancy display. So I do this:

```
<input type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" data-dojo-props="placeHolder:'Search...'" data-dojo-attach-event="onchange: search"/>
```

Now, display is fine but search is not called on change. Now I did this:

```
<input type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" data-dojo-props="placeHolder:'Search...'" data-dojo-attach-event="onchange: random_name"/>
```

The whole page crashes and debugger tells me dojo could not find the function `random_name` in the `"scope"`.

To give the whole code, [here](https://gist.github.com/4419357) they are:

***EDIT***: in place of onchange, I've tried `onChange`, `ondijitchange` or any other event like 'onclick', 'onClick', 'ondijitclick' etc but search never gets called whatever I do in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well looking at your code, and the [dojo 1.8 input example](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/TextBox.html#getting-and-manipulating-the-value) I would perhaps remove the attach event from the template and add it within the 'startup' function in your widget js file using [dojo/on](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/Evented.html).

So taking your 'MainViewWidget.js' code and your template markup, here are the amendments I would try:

first the template change...

```
<input type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" data-dojo-props="placeHolder:'Search...'" data-dojo-attach-point="inputNode"/>
```

and the widget change...

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare","dojo/dom",
        "dijit/_Widget", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
        "dojo/text!./templates/MainViewWidget.html",
        "dojo/on",
        "dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane","dijit/layout/BorderContainer","dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer"],

function(declare, dom, _Widget, _TemplatedMixin, template, on){
    return declare("package.MainViewWidget", [_Widget, _TemplatedMixin], {

    // widgetsInTemplate: true, /*keep this false, otherwise data-dojo-attach-event attribute is a pain in the ass!*/

    templateString: template,

    constructor: function(){
    },

    startup: function(){
        on(this.inputNode, "change", function(){//or just have your search function here instead
             alert('hi');
        });
    }
  });
});
```

You may need to use dojo's [lang.hitch](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch) for the event handler if you want to reference the widget using 'this' inside the 'on' handler.

Hope that helps and I didnt have any typos.

Answer (score 0):

In dijit the event name is onChange.

Api:
http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dijit/form/TextBox#onChange